# Magento -Admin Login Section

Tags: php, mysql, magento

My client has a requirement. He wants to change the Admin Panel text Which is by default "Log in to Admin Panel" to Steve's Admin Panel.Is this doable.How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

ManoMano gave you the answer. But I bet Steve would love it if you changed the picture www.yoursithehere.no/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/logo.gif. This way you can also give Steve his own image in the backend.

(I would recomend using this I made for Steve if its not too big for your design). [image: Image for Steve])

Comment: :D:D:D:D +1! Yeah, even better customization!

Answer (score 4):

You can change it in magento/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv

Answer (score 0):

Please open this Mage_Adminhtml.csv from following path \magento\app\locale\en_US and then try to find the text **Log in to Admin Panel**  and then change the text you want to put intead of the current default text near tho column(B) and then try to see it in your backend.

I hope it will change your default text as per you required